# 'jdbcExceptionTranslator' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am not using maven. spring framework 4.3.1, hibernate 5.2.1. Does Anybody have an idea?
I get following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/.../.../hibernateContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'jdbcExceptionTranslator' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate]: Bean property 'jdbcExceptionTranslator' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1518)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

.
related configuration of code partial  in hibernateContext.xml;

```
<!-- Spring Data Access Exception Translator Definition -->
<bean id="jdbcExceptionTranslator"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Template Definition -->
<bean id="hibernateTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcExceptionTranslator">
        <ref bean="jdbcExceptionTranslator" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Sounds like the version of Hibernate that you have deployed is different from the one you compiled against.

Comment: The newer `HibernateTemplate`s don't support it and actually use of the `HibernateTemplate` isn't recommended anymore, use `getCurrentSession` on the `SessionFactory` is preferred.